# How to define dependency in systemJS when using single TypeScript output file

Tags: angularjs, typescript, systemjs

How can I define dependent modules in systemJS when using a single TypeScript generated output file ?.

The problem I have is when loading an angularJS app with dependencies on other angularJS modules.
E.g. I have my boot file containing

```
import {MainAppCtrl} from "./main"
import {MainComponent} from "./main.component"

angular.module("app", ['myModule'])
    .component("mainView", new MainComponent())
    .controller("mainCtrl", MainAppCtrl)
;
angular.element(document).ready(() => {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
})
```

Then I have a 'myModule' defined in module1/module1.ts as

```
import {Module1ComponentA} from "./a.component";
import {Module1ComponentB} from "./b.component";

angular.module("myModule", [])
    .component("module1ComponentA", new Module1ComponentA())
    .component("module1ComponentB", new Module1ComponentB())
;
```

in my tsconfig.json I have configured for a single output file

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "outFile": "./output/all.bundle.js"
    //"outDir": "./output"
   },
```

and finally the System.Config

```
        System.config({
        packages: {
            output: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        },
        // depCache: {
        //  'boot': ['module1'],
        // },
        bundles: {
            '/output/all.bundle': ['boot']
        }

    });
    System.import('boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

If I remove the ['myModule'] dependency on 'app' then the app loads, but once I add the dependency I get the 'failed to instantiate module' exception.
The reason is the (system) modules in module1 are never loaded as there is no (system) dependency on them. 
I tried to use the 'depCache' in System.Config, but couldn't get it working.

The generated js code for 'boot' is

```
System.register("boot", ["main", "main.component"], function(exports_6, context_6) {
"use strict";
var __moduleName = context_6 && context_6.id;
var main_1, main_component_1, B;
return {
    setters:[
```

and if I add **"module1/module1"** to the dependency list

```
System.register("boot", ["main", "main.component", "module1/module1"],
```

then it loads.
The only hacky workaround I have found is to actually add an import statement for module1 in boot and then assign a dummy variable, and this just so module1 gets included in the dependency list.

```
import {MainAppCtrl} from "./main"
import {MainComponent} from "./main.component"

import * as Dummy1 from "./module1/module1"
var dummy1 = (<any>Dummy1);   // <<--- this will add module1 to the dependency list

angular.module("app", ['myModule'])
    .component("mainView", new MainComponent())
    .controller("mainCtrl", MainAppCtrl)
;

angular.element(document).ready(() => {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
})
```

How can I add this dependency in the System.Config ?

Answer (score 0):

try modifying your system.config into:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {
      scripts: { 
        format: 'cjs',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    ...
  });
  ...
 </script>
```

Comment: thank you fro the quick reply, unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @JesperKristiansen is your System.import('boot') file located in the same path as the config one?

Comment: no, all files are compiled into a single file located in (relative to index.html) './output/all.bundle.js'